# Connect remote PC with credentials

Tags: vb.net, vb6, network-programming, pinvoke

I have been trying to connect remote PC(with known credentials and on the same network) to my PC with  vb.net but struck at following Error:

> Managed Debugging Assistant 'PInvokeStackImbalance' : 'A call to PInvoke function 'WindowsApp1!WindowsApp1.Form1::WNetAddConnection2' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.'

Whereas same code has been executed flawlessly in Vb6.

Code:

```
Private Declare Function WNetAddConnection2 Lib "mpr.dll" Alias "WNetAddConnection2A" (lpNetResource As NETRESOURCE, ByVal lpPassword As String, ByVal lpUserName As String, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function WNetCancelConnection2 Lib "mpr.dll" Alias "WNetCancelConnection2A" (ByVal lpName As String, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal fForce As Long) As Long

Private Structure NETRESOURCE

    Dim dwType As Long
    Dim lpRemoteName As String

End Structure

Private Const RESOURCETYPE_DISK = &H1

Private Sub ConnectToPC()

    Dim networkResource As New NETRESOURCE
    Dim lon As Long

    With networkResource

        .dwType = RESOURCETYPE_DISK
        .lpRemoteName = "\\192.168.1.1"

    End With

    lon = WNetAddConnection2(networkResource, "123", "ADMIN", 0)

End Sub
```

Exception is thrown at **lon** and code coudn't execute further.

I am new to VB.net language.Any assistance would be very helpful.

Comment: Might be easier just to Process.Start `net use` ?

Comment: In the signature replace `(lpNetResource As NETRESOURCE, ...` with `(By Ref lpNetResource As NETRESOURCE, ...` because the `NETRESOURCE` here is a structure and not a class. Also, replace any `Long` with `Integer`.

Comment: Sorry Caius but I couldn't get you. @CaiusJard

Comment: Thank you @JQSOFT for your help. I changed as you suggest and now error is out of equation but another problem surfaced. Now, My code is running without error irrespective of connectivity. so even I remove my connection or entered FALSE Password or USERNAME or IP, it executes normally as if it is connecting.

Comment: You'r welcome. Force it to close the connection, pass `1` in `fForce` parameter of the `WNetCancelConnection2`. If there is a file still opened or unfinished job in the current session, the `WNetCancelConnection2` fails without forcing to close.

Comment: First I checked  **lon** status with msgbox and it shows the value 487 then I used ` lon = WNetCancelConnection2("\\192.168.1.1", 0, 1)` immediate after connection and then check status of **lon** and then again checked the ststus of **lon** and it comes 2250.problem is still persist. What would be the value of **lon** if connection fails?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask a new question, don't start off with one question, then start asking others in the comments

Comment: it is related to my query. it isn't new question @CaiusJard . Your help will be highly appreciated if you can answer my query. thank you

Comment: The original problem that this question was asking about, is solved. A new question is needed for that same reason that I can't start out asking "How do I turn on my computer", then change it to "how to I launch visual studio", then "how do I load my project" then "how do I group this list in linq" - grouping a list in LINQ is not related to turning on my computer, even though i needed to do that before I could group a list

Comment: Hi @CaiusJard. I am newbie to this platform so wasn't aware about the functionality but I guess now I am. Thanks for the direction.

Answer (score 1):

From JQSOFT's comment:

> In the signature replace (`lpNetResource As NETRESOURCE, ...`
>
> with
>
> (`ByRef lpNetResource As NETRESOURCE, ...` because the NETRESOURCE here is a 
>    structure and not a class. Also, replace any `Long` with `Integer`